# Is it possible to use custom (own) HLSL shader in 3Ds Max?

Tags: hlsl, 3dsmax

I am looking for a way testing my shaders (quicker) and i think is there any ways of using own shader in 3ds max, and is it possible to pass some parameters to it, it's desirable to do not use plugins.. (maybe maxscript or something...)

Thank you for help...

Comment: What about Rendermonkey or FX Composer?

Comment: Thank you, FX Composer looks like thing i need.